# MagicSuggest add custom tags with HTML or jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, magicsuggest

I'm creating some input fields to insert search-tags (exactly same method as StackOverflow). It works great when the field is loading with no tags.

The problem is that i want to add custom tags to the field onLoad. I know from the [Documentation](http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/) that you can add tags which is entered as suggestions, but the tags I want to add is not inside the database (which I'm loading from).

I've tried this:

```
1.
<input type="text" value="tag1,tag2,tag3" />

2.
<input type="text" value="['tag1','tag2','tag3']" />

3.
$('.tags').magicSuggest({
     width: 300,
     maxSuggestions: 5,
     data: json,
     ...,
     value: ["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
});
```

and more stuff like that.

I've also thought about running through the tags and add it to the `data: json` with ID's and then use `value: [ID1,ID2,ID3]` but there simply must be an easier way!

I've created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4MnW/

Hoping someone can help me to put the final touch on the script.

**UPDATED:**

Each item should be activated individual and not with the same class. After that it could be added with `.addToSelection()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the [FAQ](http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/). Check out the question "The value property doesn't work when working with remote data."

The main reason why this is not trivial is that the client-side component has no idea about what data it suggests as it is loaded through ajax. It was created in a way that it can only adds items that it suggests. It cannot enter free entries on its own. This is simply because it should allow you to know when a value is not found even though you expected it to be.

The best way to preload existing or non-existing values is to use parameters in your initial ajax load and tell the server what kind of data you want to preload for your initial load. An example is provided in the FAQ.

You can also check out https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest/issues/21 which is a similar problematic for a different use case approach.

Cheers